# Is it possible to show the appwidget in the application menu and not on the homescreen in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

Is it possible to show the appwidget in the application menu and not on the homescreen in android ?

In my application I have to notify the Launcher icon with a numeric value, I have created a widget which works fine and is seen on the home screen but I want it in the applications menu ?

Answer (score 0):

No. The application menu (at least the default application menu in the default Home application) does not implement the Widget Host interface, so there is no way to do that.

You might find a custom Home application that provides widget host services but haven't really seen anyone do that.